# Storing tags in SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a table with around 7000 quiz questions (it will be growing). Each question has a list of tags.

For example, question "Which golf competition takes place on the weekend of the third Friday in July?" has tags "Sport, Golf, Days of the Week".

What would be the best way to store the tags in SQL database?

Currently they are stored as a string, and when I need them I do some absolutely ugly string manipulation.

I need to be able to easily add new tags (I was thinking about using https://sean.is/poppin/tags/), and the easiest and nicest way seems to be by using arrays. Of course, I could just change this array into a string, but it feels wrong to be changing string to arrays and then back again.

I also need to be able to list all questions with a specific tag. I don't want to use a wildcard, because that creates some problems. For example, if I ask for ART, i might get pARTnerships as well.

Normalising an array and then putting it into database kinda works, but it would be a mess if I ask for a list of all tags.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the database, but in general I would recommend a `QuizTags` table with one row per tag on each quiz.

Comment: It's a `ManyToMany` relation, isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't store arrays as strings in databases. It makes fetching them harder and forces you to create more code to unpack and use them later.

## My suggestion (Multiple tables)

I suggest adding a new table with a key to your main table.

**Questions**:

```
| uid | question                                   |
| 1   | Which golf... ...third Friday in July?     |
| 2   | How many golfers... ...screw in lightbulb? |
```

**Tags**:

```
| uid | questionid | tag              |
| 1   | 1          | Sport            |
| 2   | 1          | Golf             |
| 3   | 1          | Days of the Week |
| 4   | 2          | Joke             |
| 5   | 2          | Golf             |
| 6   | 2          | Lightbulb        |
```

This will allow you to easily pull every question with a specific tag, and easily list every tag from a specific question.

### Query: All tags for specific question

```
$tags = query("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE questionid='2'");
//returns list of tags from question with ID 2
```

### Query: All questions with specific tag

```
$questions = query("SELECT questionid FROM tags WHERE tag='Golf'");
//will return all questionids with tag "Golf"
```

---

## Single Table Option

If you want to keep everything inside one table, then you could use JSON. You can store a JSON array in your database because it is simply a string.

So, in PHP, say you have an array of tags:

```
$tags = ["Sport", "Golf", "Days of the Week"];
```

Now, you want to store this to your database, so you just use `[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)`:

```
$tags = json_encode($tags);
```

Now `$tags` can safely be stored in your database, and when you need them later all you have to do is [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) them:

```
$tags = json_decode($tags_from_db, true);
```

Now, searching for questions with a specific tag can still be pretty easy when doing it this way.
Say you want to list all questions that have the tag "Sport", you can do that via:

```
query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE tag LIKE '%\"Sport\"%'");
```

Comment: I like your answer. By using multiple tables, I can avoid wildcard. Instead of using `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE tag LIKE '%Sport%'`, I'd use `SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = 'Sport'`

Comment: @RobertMoritz exactly! I believe that is your best way, but I wanted to show you a way to do it with your current setup as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a many to many sql table. here is an example: 
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18503/1)

```
create table quiz_questions (id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, question TEXT, answer TEXT);
create table quiz_tags (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, tag TEXT);
create table quiz_questions_tags (question_id INT, tag_id INT);

insert into quiz_questions(question, answer) VALUES ('q1','a1');
insert into quiz_questions(question, answer) VALUES ('q2','a2');
insert into quiz_questions(question, answer) VALUES ('q3','a3');

insert into quiz_tags(tag) VALUES ('sports');
insert into quiz_tags(tag) VALUES ('history');
insert into quiz_tags(tag) VALUES ('other');


insert into quiz_questions_tags(question_id, tag_id) VALUES (1,1);
insert into quiz_questions_tags(question_id, tag_id) VALUES (2,2);
insert into quiz_questions_tags(question_id, tag_id) VALUES (3,3);
insert into quiz_questions_tags(question_id, tag_id) VALUES (3,2);
insert into quiz_questions_tags(question_id, tag_id) VALUES (3,1);
```

Sql query:

```
select q.* from quiz_questions q, quiz_tags t, quiz_questions_tags qt where q.id = qt.question_id and t.id = qt.tag_id
and t.tag = 'sports'
```